# Snowflake: $SYS_FACADE in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, materialized-views, information-schema

I'm querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and for MATERIALIZED VIEWS with columns having an AVG() aggregation I do always get two rows for one existing column with COLUMN_NAME like this:

- PROFIT_AVG$SYS_FACADE$0
- PROFIT_AVG$SYS_FACADE$1

First of all, what does SYS_FACADE mean?
Second, how can I filter the duplicate row since they have different values for precision/scale, and which would it be SYS_FACADE$1?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

1. Number datatype in snowflake has scale '0' (digits to right of decimal point) while float will hold valid higher scale value in case of average. It's snowflakes internal way of handling average calculation.
   2.You can see that in the 'MV definition' in the UI , it will autogenerate 2 columns (comment as Internal aggregate).
   3.why are you looking to filter the columns.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why it's two internal columns for one real column I can use in a SELECT.
I need to query the catalog to autogenerate SELECT statements so I need the real column list instead..

Comment: thats the internal functioning of snowlfkae.

Comment: You can try below query for list of columns in this case :                                                                              
select table_name,max(split_part(column_name,'$SYS_FACADE$',1)) column_name from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'MV_AVG'  --replace your MV name
group by table_name,split_part(column_name,'$SYS_FACADE$',1);